# Confusion in first-order logic inference

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence

I'm having some difficulty with understanding the following paragraphs taken from the book Artificial Intelligence A modern approach, regarding first-order logic inference:

The technique of propositionalization can be made completely general; that is, every first-order knowledge base and query can be propositionalized in such a way that entailment is preserved. Thus, we have a complete decision procedure for entailment....or perhaps not. There is a problem: When the knowledge base includes a function symbol, the set of possible ground term substitutions is infinite! For eg, if the knowledge base mentions the *Father* symbol, then infinitely many nested terms such as *Father(Father(Father(John)))* can be constructed. Our propositional algorithms will have difficulty with an infinitely large set of sentences.

Fortunately, there is a famous theorem due to Jacques Herbrand(1930) to the effect that if a sentence is entailed by the original, first-order knowledge base, then there is a proof involving just a *finite* subset of the propositionalized knowledge base.Since any such subset has a maximum depth of nesting among it's ground terms, we can find the subset y first generating all the instantiations with constant symbols (*Richard* and *John*), then all terms of depth 1 (*Father(Richard)* and *Father(John)*), then all terms of depth 2, and so on, until we are able to construct a propositional proof of the entailed sentence.

---

I understand that infinite nested terms are generated during substitution- but the next paragraph talking about the theorem totally goes over my head.

Answer (score 0):

Herbrand's theorem is semidecidable. The goal is to find an instantiation where the query is not satisfied anymore. You start with depth 1 and continue until you find an unsatisfiability.
It might loop endlessly if it is satisfiable though.